# NodeJS dbus not working

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, raspberry-pi, dbus

I'm trying to get status from omxplayer with NodeJS via DBus, to do that i'm just trying to execuce shell script:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    #set -x
    OMXPLAYER_DBUS_ADDR="/tmp/omxplayerdbus"
    OMXPLAYER_DBUS_PID="/tmp/omxplayerdbus.pid"
    export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=`cat $OMXPLAYER_DBUS_ADDR`
    export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_PID=`cat $OMXPLAYER_DBUS_PID`
    [ -z "$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS" ] && { echo "Must have DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS" >&2; exit 1; }
    duration=`dbus-send --print-reply=literal --session --reply-timeout=500 --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.omxplayer /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Duration`
    [ $? -ne 0 ] && exit 1
    duration="$(awk '{print $2}' <<< "$duration")"
    position=`dbus-send --print-reply=literal --session --reply-timeout=500 --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.omxplayer /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Position`
    [ $? -ne 0 ] && exit 1
    position="$(awk '{print $2}' <<< "$position")"
    playstatus=`dbus-send --print-reply=literal --session --reply-timeout=500 --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.omxplayer /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.PlaybackStatus`
    [ $? -ne 0 ] && exit 1
    playstatus="$(sed 's/^ *//;s/ *$//;' <<< "$playstatus")"
    paused="true"
    [ "$playstatus" == "Playing" ] && paused="false"
    echo "Duration: $duration"
    echo "Position: $position"
    echo "Paused: $paused"
    ;;
```

with

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('bash status.sh', function() {
    console.log(arguments);
})
```

but it prints

```
    { '0':
       { [Error: Command failed: Failed to open connection to "session" message bus: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
       ] killed: false, code: 1, signal: null },
      '1': '',
      '2': 'Failed to open connection to "session" message bus: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.\n' }
```

When I execute that script directly in console it works. NodeJS is running on Raspberry Pi.

**UPDATE:**

I have also tried "node-dbus" and "dbus-native" modules, but none of them worked for me, but maybe I used them incorrectly? To execute

```
dbus-send --print-reply=literal --session --reply-timeout=500 --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.omxplayer /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Duration
```

I used
**dbus-native**

```
    var exec = require('child_process').exec;
    exec('cat /tmp/omxplayerdbus', function(error, data, stderr) {
        data = data.replace("\n",'');
        var dbus = require('dbus-native');
        var bus = dbus.sessionBus({
            busAddress: data //unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-7BuZanKhmv,guid=7fafe7baa2d38357478f04ff5429712a
        });
        bus.invoke({
            path: '/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2',
            destination: 'org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.omxplayer',
            'interface': 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Position'
        }, function(err, res) {
            console.log(arguments);
        });
        //And this
        var conn = dbus({
            busAddress: data
        });
        conn.message({
            path:'/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2',
            destination: 'org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.omxplayer',
            type: dbus.messageType.methodCall
        });
        conn.on('message', function(msg) { console.log(msg); }).on('error', function() {
            console.log(arguments);
        }).on('connect', function() {
            console.log(arguments);
        });
    });
```

both of these methods throws me this error:

```
    events.js:72
            throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
                  ^
    Error: write EPIPE
        at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
        at Object.afterWrite (net.js:720:19)
```

**UPDATE 2**

I'm now using "dbus-native" module and still keep getting "EPIPE" error. I have checked "Handshake.js" and there is everything alright, so I dumped stdin and stdout messages:

```
    {stdin}AUTH EXTERNAL 30

    {stdout}OK df028c4a159a4db39ccc41c0542b9e3b

    {stdin}BEGIN

    {stdin}lmo/org/freedesktop/DBussorg.freedesktop.DBussHellosorg.freedesktop.DBus
    PuTTY{stdin}l5�o/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2sorg.freedesktop.DBus.PropertiessGets org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.omxplayegss org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.omxplayePosition
```

{stdout} - stdout message line
{stdin} - stdin message line

and then "EPIPE".

**UPDATE 3**

I have found out that "EPIPE" error is throwed right after first dbus "DATA" command, in this case it's

`lmo/org/freedesktop/DBussorg.freedesktop.DBussHellosorg.freedesktop.DBus
PuTTY{stdin}l5�o/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2sorg.freedesktop.DBus.PropertiessGets org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.omxplayegss org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.omxplayePosition`

i'm new in communications via dbus, but according to [DBus protocol](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#auth-protocol-overview), messages should be sent `DATA <data in hex encoding>`, but `dbus-native` sends messages without `DATA` command name.

Comment: have you tried any existing node libraries (I'm author of one, dbus-native ) ?

Comment: Looks like it can't connect to that address. Try to test with socat like `echo -e "\0AUTH ANONYMOUS \r\n" | socat abstract-client:/tmp/dbus-7BuZanKhmv -`

Comment: Socat prints out `exactly 2 addresses required (there are 1)` when I add second argument it prints `unknown device/address`. What address should be in second one argument? Tried many combinations.

Comment: Last "-" is the second address (stdout), socat forwards data from stdin to dbus and from dbus to stdout.

Comment: Oh thanks, didn't noticed that one. Now command works and the output is: "OK b5f73229fd018db5a12471ee542a5747"

Comment: I still think address is not passed correctly for some reason. BTW why would you use "cat" to read file in node? fs.readFile() ?  To check if initial connection is successful try to set breakpoints or add console.log()s to https://github.com/sidorares/node-dbus/blob/master/lib/handshake.js#L77

Comment: The second connection method with `bus.invoke` connects and prints GUID. But I can't get any message from it.

Comment: ok, I have not read your code carefully. I don't think you have "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Position" interface. Try to use d-feet to introspect your object. Likely you need to access "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" interface and call "Get" member, with "Position" and "org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.omxplayer" as parameters. See http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#standard-interfaces-properties

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read dbus object propery using [properties api](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#standard-interfaces-properties). Note that last parameter of dbus-send is interface.member, so the message you are sending would be

```
var bus = dbus.sessionBus({ busAddress: fs.readFileSync('/tmp/omxplayerdbus', 'ascii').trim()})
bus.invoke({
  path: "/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2",
  interface: "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties",
  member: "Get",
  destination: "org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.omxplayer",
  signature: "ss",
  body: [
    "org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.omxplayer",
    "Position"
  ]
}, function(err, position) {
  console.log(err, position);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, for explanation, but I still keep getting `EPIPE` error when using invoke method. Error comes from `abstractsocket/node_modules/exec_stream/index.js child.stdin.on('error')` event. In Handshake.js there is everything ok, it executes `AUTH EXTERNAL 30` and receives `OK`. I have updated my question, added more details (see "Update 2").

Comment: looks like dbus drops connection during handshake, not sure why.

Comment: When I comment out message sending method, connections stays alive forever, no errors. But after first message is sent it throws error.

Comment: that's probably because handshake is incomplete and server disconnects if it's incorrect.  Can you try to use dbus-native from master and run https://github.com/sidorares/node-dbus/blob/master/bin/dbus-dissect.js to monitor communication?

Comment: I have updated `dbus-natvie` and ran `dbus-dissect.js`, but error came out because `process.env.DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` was undefined, so I temporary assigned address to `fs.readFileSync('/tmp/omxplayerdbus', 'ascii').trim()` and then launched dbus client, but client always prints out `Didn't write bytes to closed stream` and dissect prints justs `Server started...`